# Excel Date Range Cannot Exceed 365 Days

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

Calculate a % leak rate based upon prior activity date and current activity date, but if period exceeds 365 days, use 365 day maximum period.

Formula is:
`=IF(A7="","-",((C7/$B$4)/(DAYS(A7,A6)/365)))`
where A7 is current date, A6 is prior date, C7 is the quantity added, B4 is the full capacity.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. What are you asking here? Please edit your post to state a clear question.

Comment: Does `=IF(A7="","-",IF(DAYS(A7,A6)>=365,(C7/$B$4),((C7/$B$4)/(DAYS(A7,A6)/365))))` help?

Answer (score 0):

`=IF(A7="","-",((C7/$B$4)/(MIN(DAYS(A7,A6),365)/365)))`

If your formula works as advertised but you want the formula to stop at 365 days.  I would use a `MIN` formula.  If the days are below 365, that is the minimum and will be divided by 365.  If the days are more than 365, then 365 is minimum and will be divided by 365.